# How to set an attribute value on a new instance of a class at run-time

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, attributes, typedescriptor

I'm trying to set an attribute on a method when I create the object but not sure how to go about it (or if it's possible).

This is what I've tried so far:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass
{
    public abstract string DynamicAttributeValue { get; }

    public AbstractClass()
    {
        // Set the Attribute on THIS instance
        TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(typeof(AbstractClass).GetMethod("MyMethod"),
            new Attribute[] {
                new ConditionalAttribute(DynamicAttributeValue)
        });
    }

    public void MyMethod()
    {
    }
}

class MyConcreteClass : AbstractClass
{
    public override string DynamicAttributeValue => "MyRunTimeValue";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyConcreteClass myClass = new MyConcreteClass();

        string callingMethodName = "MyMethod";
        MethodInfo methodInfo = myClass.GetType().GetMethod(callingMethodName);

        var attributes = methodInfo.GetCustomAttributes();
    }
}
```

Comment: `TypeDescriptor` doesn't actually add attributes to the target class -- it just adds them to the `TypeDescriptor` system. You can only read such attributes with `TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes`

Comment: Are you trying to set custom attributes / attribute values for each instance of a class? Because that's not how attributes work. Attributes are set on a class, not the object of that class.

Comment: @canton7 Ah okay I didn't know that.. Yes I'm trying to set the attribute of a method, on an individual instance of that class